# Scrapy returning duplicate item fields when scraping/downloading images but scrapes unique images

Tags: python, scrapy

Scrapy is returning duplicate item fields in the output, but will scrape/download unique images. The scraper works fine when I am not scraping for images, returns all unique values for each item.

The only lines I modified in the settings.py is:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 300,
}
IMAGES_STORE = '.../posters'
```

Here is my parse function that returns duplicate values but unique image files:

```
def parse(self, response):
    item = AnimeItem()
    for anime in response.css('.seasonal-anime'):
        item['rating'] = anime.css('.score::text').get().strip()
        item['airdate'] = anime.css('.remain-time::text').get().strip()
        item['url'] = anime.css('.link-title').attrib['href']
        item['title'] = anime.css('.link-title::text').get()
        item['synopsis'] = anime.css('.preline::text').get()
        try:
            item['image_urls'] = [anime.css('.image a img').attrib['src']]
        except KeyError:
            item['image_urls'] = [anime.css('.image a img').attrib['data-src']]
        yield item
```

The reason I need to check for a `src` attribute is because the page(https://myanimelist.net/anime/season) lazy-loads elements but those lazy-loaded elements won't return a `src` attribute, raises a `KeyError` despite it existing in the html. So I check for a `data-src` attribute which returns the identical value. The `data-src` attribute does not exist for the first dozen elements. I tried using xpath to see if it will read the `src` attribute but it does the same thing.

I was able to get it to work once with an if/else statement but I've since lost the code because I wanted to use a try/except. I think it was something like this:

```
image_src = anime.css('.image a img').attrib['src']
image_data_src = anime.css('.image a img').attrib['data-src']
if image_src:
    item['image_urls'] = [image_src]
elif image_data_src:
    item['image_urls'] = [image_data_src]
```

This particular snippet doesn't work because the first 2 lines in this section will raise a `KeyError`. It was something along this line that worked.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by starting a new project as I suspected there was an issue with the pipeline but was not able to find it.

I ended up using this snippet to check for `data-src` and `src` attributes:

```
if element.css('.image a img::attr(src)').get() is None:
    item['image_urls'] = element.css('.image a img::attr(data-src)').extract()
else:
    item['image_urls'] = element.css('.image a img::attr(src)').extract()
```

I'm still confused why this snippet yields unique images but create duplicates in the rest of the fields.

```
try:
    item['image_urls'] = [anime.css('.image a img').attrib['src']]
except KeyError:
    item['image_urls'] = [anime.css('.image a img').attrib['data-src']]
```

Thank you!